# opencv undistortion (camera calibration)

Tags: opencv, distortion

I am having problems using opencv's undistort() api.

Currently I am trying to verify the calibration results by comparing the results with GML calibration tool box (//graphics.cs.msu.ru/en/node/909).

**Below are the results obtained by using *GML***

---

```
=== Intrinsic ===
778.200465 0.000000 264.299668
0.000000 757.938633 383.228433
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
=== Distortion ===
-0.102929 0.142385 0.001972 0.007185 
=== Position ===
0.0 0.0 0.0
=== Extrinsic ===
0.022835  0.913067  0.407170  -13.413557
0.642153  -0.325546  0.694016  -176.271870
0.766236  0.245618  -0.593763  251.019585
0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000

pixle error [0.12, 0.06]
```

---

**Below are the results from *OPENCV 2.4.8 release***

---

```
%YAML:1.0
nframes: 2
image_width: 480
image_height: 752
square_size: 15.
flags: 0
camera_matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 7.7831650886449142e+002, 0., 2.6427482436286419e+002, 0.,
       7.5794845379782328e+002, 3.8328330268344854e+002, 0., 0., 1. ]
distortion_coefficients: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 5
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -1.0303815300339793e-001, 1.4247900680485645e-001,
       1.9600293643082536e-003, 7.1852707322515265e-003, 0. ]
avg_reprojection_error: 1.3913581417364859e-001
per_view_reprojection_errors: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 2
   cols: 1
   dt: f
   data: [ 1.34592891e-001, 1.47803366e-001 ]
```

---

Results from GML and OPENCV looks comparable to my eyes, but the undistortion results looks completely different.

Attached the 2 images

showing diff between orignal and gml undistorted
- "2_gml_calib_undistorted.bmp" - used gml toolbox undistortion 
[image]

showing diff between orignal and opencv undistorted
- "3_opencv2.4.8_calib_undistorted.bmp" - using opencv 
[image]

Also tried feeding GML calibration data to opencv undistort() function and results looks similar to that of opencv. So I concluded the problem is with undistort api usage. 
But I cannot still fix the issue.

Pls Note:
I use the following opencv apis

- `findChessboardCorners(viewGray, boardData.boardSize, point2Dbuf,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);`
- `calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, *cameraMatrix,*distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs, flags|CV_CALIB_FIX_K3|CV_CALIB_FIX_K4|CV_CALIB_FIX_K5,TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100,DBL_EPSILON));`
- `undistort(view, rview, *cameraMatrix, *distCoeffs);`

Any pointers to resolve this issue would be of great help.

Thanks,

Hari

Comment: Did you use the cornerSubPix function to refine the found chessboard corners?
Also, why did you fix the K3, K4 and K5 params? This will greatly effect the distortion calib!

Comment: I want to verify the calibration result with known available reference like GML toolbox. GML toolbox provide only 4 distortion parameters, so for verification purpose i fixed the K3 , K4 & K5 so that i can compare with it directly. But thanks for your suggestion, I will start to play with it, once I have the result which can be compared with GML. (Currently, though calibration data from opencv & GML toolbox are comparable opencv undistortion results are different when compared to GML.

Comment: Obviously they are different; Your termination criteria are probably different. The point where the algoritm 'stops' depends on what the results are.
Also; how sure are you that the GML toolbox does not do subpixel localisation?
If you don't care about getting the exact same results (but just better) I can recommend using the circle pattern from OpenCV. Its fare more accurate.

Comment: Nallath, I tried plugging in the GML calibration results to opencv undistortion function. I expected undistortion results to be similar to the output given by GML toolbox, but it is similar to opencv results shown above. Can I conclude the difference is with undistortion functions employed by opencv and GML? Between I tried using circle pattern and reprojection error was quite high. After switching to checker board and fine tuning the termination criteria i got low reprojection errors.

Comment: Generally, the projection error is about 2x as low with the circles when compared to the checkerboard. 
But yeah, I think its a difference in implementation.